Why can't ghosts move snow in Harry Potter?
In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, it is mentioned that ghosts can't move snow.

But then he heard a rustle and saw a little eddy of dislodged snow in the bush to which Hermione had pointed. Ghosts could not move snow.
Chapter 17, Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows

On the other hand, we see in Chamber of Secrets that Myrtle is able to splash water over people.

Myrtle gave a tragic sob, rose up in the air, turned over and dived head first into the toilet, splashing water all over them and vanishing from sight; from the direction of her muffled sobs, she had come to rest somewhere in the U-bend.
Chapter 9, Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets

Why exactly could a ghost not move snow when it could move water?
There was an earlier question on the site "Can ghosts affect the physical world?" which was answered that ghosts can definitively affect the physical world. This is in direct contrast to ghosts not being able to move snow, and so I submit that this question is not a duplicate of that one.
Edit: However, there's another answer on the same question (not accepted) that explains that ghosts cannot affect solids. That answers my question well enough.

Because it's not whimsical and cute.

Great question!

@TheAsh no, the question you have mentioned has an accepted answer of "Yes, ghosts can affect the physical world." That is very obviously in contradiction of ghosts not being able to move snow.

There's an answer in the linked question that mentions the ghosts can't affect solids whilst they can affect glasses and liquids. It sounds like it would be a good answer for this question whilst contradicting the accepted answer of the other question.

@Clockwork you are right. That's a well crafted answer. Editing my question now.
